# anonymous window.setTimeout function reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, clearinterval

Using Tampermonkey to change the behavior of a website. Have some problems with a website with the following code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
            jQuery(window).load(function() {
                 window.setTimeout(function() {
                     window.location.replace(window.location.href);
                 }, 180E3);
             });
         }
</script>
```

How does one remove/prevent it reloading the page?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you please become more specific ? Your question it is not clear. What is the actual problem ?

Comment: I want the page to stop auto reloading! I'm a Tampermonkey/Javascript rookie and this does my head in. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without messing that much with `jQuery`, **if your script runs before that piece of code** you can do the following:

```
jQuery.fn.load = function() {
  console.log("Tried to reload the page!")
}

// Then the following, outputs 'Tried to reload the page!' and does nothing else
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  // code
})
```

If you still need the `load` function afterwards you *could* do the following:

```
var oldLoad = jQuery.fn.load
var undesiredCallback = "function() {
             window.setTimeout(function() {
                 window.location.replace(window.location.href);
             }, 180E3);
         }"
jQuery.fn.load = function(callback) {
  if(callback.toString() !== undesiredCallback) {
    oldLoad(callback);
  }
}
```

But it's browser dependent and very unreliable

Another way would be adding a `onbeforeunload` event, but that would pop a prompt on your tab:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Stay here please";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also override setTimeout functionallity.

```
var oldSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = function(func,interval){ 
    if(typeof func === "function" && func.toString().indexOf('window.location.replace(window.location.href)') > -1){
        /*do nothing*/
    }else{ 
        oldSetTimeout(func,interval) 
    } 
}
```